# Platform-Specific Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

[Here is the Maven Repository](http://first.wpi.edu/FRC/roborio/maven/release/edu/wpi/cscore/java/cscore/1.0.2/) that I'm trying to use. A snippet from my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.wpi.cscore.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>cscore</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When run, it grabs the `cscore-1.0.2.pom` file just fine, but then it goes searching for `cscore-1.0.2.jar` which doesn't exist - if you look in the repo, each JAR is platform-specific, and is named accordingly (e.g. `cscore-1.0.2-linux.jar`).

I've tried:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.wpi.cscore.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>cscore</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.wpi.cscore.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>cscore</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2-linux</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

It gets the `cscore-1.0.2.pom` fine but then it goes looking in the `1.0.2-linux/` directory for the JAR, which simply doesn't exist. Is there a way to tell Maven that the JAR file it is looking for will be named something else? Or is this simply not a valid Maven repository?

Thanks!

Comment: Just read how you can deploy a jar file using maven. You will know what is significance of all groupId, artifactId etc

Comment: @Smith, can you please provide your error stack trace?

Comment: @Smith, please check if you can download the jar file from the maven repository which you have given here. If yes, you can manually place that in your local cache (maven repository). I could able to download it and also check if firewall policy has any filters.

Comment: What you need to give if those artifacts are named like I saw is that you need to add a for example for linux `<classifier>linux</classifier>` for your dependencies. And you shouldn't give a dependency on the `<type>pom</type>`.

Comment: @khmarbaise That fixed it! Exactly what I needed. Strange that I can't find a reference to the "classifier" tag anywhere in the official Maven reference docs (I guess I wasn't looking hard enough).

Answer (score 1):

There should be one [and only one] artifact addressable via a coordinate [group-id, artifact-id, version].

These platform-specific artifacts were likely pushed into the repository manually and can't be referred to individually via the expected maven dependency POM element.

The easiest short-term solution would be to manually extract the dependency/dependencies and install each one with its own unique maven coordinates in your local repository. Then refer to that artifact using its local coordinates from the  element in your project's POM.

Unfortunately that makes it impossible for maven to *automatically* detect and download a newer version of the artifact in the remote repo.

The long-term solution would be to petition the keepers of the external dependency's project, asking them to re-consider how they identify and install their platform-specific artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason we've started using a Maven build script is to run automated testing on Travis CI for pull requests - I'm not sure if we have access to the local Maven repository due to the fact that everything is run in a locked-down VM.

Comment: BTW, here's a reference to artifact classifiers in the [docs for the Maven `deploy` plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html).